# batch file uses the arguments of previous execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments, parameter-passing

I am very amateur on batch script, trying to write a batch file to accelerate my work. 
But every time I run this batch file, it uses the arguments of previous execution (instead of using the current arguments)

I can use the following lines to repeat the error.

```
REM source code begin
@echo off

set aim=%1

if "%aim%"=="download" (
    set taskShortName=%2
    set action=%3
    echo %taskShortName%
    echo %action%
    echo download things
)
REM source code end

the output is:
C:\Users\Charles>dbg_arg.bat download 20160901 init
20160901
init
download things
C:\Users\Charles>dbg_arg.bat download 20160901 init
20160901
init
download things
C:\Users\Charles>dbg_arg.bat download 20160901 resume
20160901
init <----- ERROR
download things
C:\Users\Charles>dbg_arg.bat download 20160901 resume
20160901
resume
download things
C:\Users\Charles>
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are writing *and* reading the same variables in one parenthesised block of code...

Comment: Thanks. I read the link. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aschipfl stated, you need delayed expansion. This means you have to the line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your code and address variables you have changed inside your if-block as `!var!` rather than `%var%`.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set aim=%1

if "%aim%"=="download" (
    set taskShortName=%2
    set action=%3
    echo !taskShortName!
    echo !action!
    echo download things
)
```

Comment: Got it. What I really need is to acquire all the arguments at the very beginning of the script, so as to avoid "delayed expansion". Thanks! Guys.

Comment: Indeed, it is :-) If your problem is solved now, please mark my answer as a solution.

Comment: I thought I could parse the successive arguments according to the first argument. That was why I use that "if-block". I think it is a good habit to parse all the arguments before real logic begins.

Comment: I see a green "tick" now. Sorry I am too amateur on using this website, though I read posts too much. :)